# Using a string variable name to perform vlookup in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm very new to VBA so please bear with me...

I'm trying to perform a vlookup where the workbook and worksheet referred to in table_array are string variables.

Specifically, the line of code I'm having trouble with is this:

```vb
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[5],'[Var1]Var2'!C5,1,FALSE,)),""NOT IN TRACKER"",""IN TRACKER"")"
```

`Var1` is the name of the workbook I'm looking in and `Var2` is the name of the worksheet. Both are stored as strings.

Every time my program gets to this line of code it triggers an application-defined or object-defined error.

Changed to

```vb
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[5],'[" & Var1 & "]" & Var2 & "'!C5,1,FALSE,)),""NOT IN TRACKER"",""IN TRACKER"")"
```

Comment: Variables need to be outside the quotes, concatenated with `&`: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[5],'[" & Var1 & "]" & Var2 & "'!C5,1,FALSE,)),""NOT IN TRACKER"",""IN TRACKER"")"`

Comment: Hmmm, still no luck...

Comment: Then `Debug.Print` the entire string and inspect the output in the Immediate Window. Copy this output and paste it into a cell ... Excel should complain and hopefully give a hint as to what is wrong with the formula. What are the values of `Var1` and `Var2`?

Comment: Extra `,` here after FALSE: `... & "'!C5,1,FALSE,)`  You need to remove that.  FYI you can use MATCH() if you're just checking one column.

Comment: This is what it outputs: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[5],'[2021_Delivery_Tracker.xlsx]WB Deliveries (07-02)'!C5,1,FALSE,)),"NOT IN TRACKER","IN TRACKER")

Which is exactly what it should look like, I'm pretty sure. But it still gives the same error...

Comment: Firstly,  fix the error Tim points out - remove the extra `,`.  Secondly,  is the specified wb open?  If it's not you'll need to include the full path inside the `[  ]`

Comment: Oh my god it worked! It's always a damn comma or semicolon.... Thanks guys!!!