# VBA Vlookup from different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to write a vlookup code that uses the lookups tab as the array (A:B) and the revenue tab where the vlookup is in cell Y2. I need it to fill all the way through column Y.

```
Sub VLOOKUP()

Dim LookupsLastRow As Long
Dim RevenueLastRow As Long
Dim LookupsSheet As Worksheet
Dim RevenueSheet As Worksheet


'What are the names of our worksheets?
Set LookupsSheet = Worksheets("Lookups")
Set RevenueSheet = Worksheets("Revenue")

'Determine last row of source
With LookupsSheet
    LookupsLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With RevenueSheet
    'Determine last row in col P
    RevenueLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    'Apply our formula
    .Range("Y2:Y" & RevenueLastRow).Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP(V2,"Lookups"!$A$2:$B$" & LookupsLastRow & ",2,0)"
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: You already know how to [insert a variable into a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42503316/11683), just put the sheet name [back inside the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68549699/11683).

Comment: How about modifying it slightly? "=VLOOKUP(V2,Lookups!$A$2:$B$" & LookupsLastRow & ",2,0)"

Comment: I would recommend looking into Power Query for this.

Comment: I would highly recommend dropping `VLookUp()` for `Index( OutputSheet!B:B, Match(InputSheet!A1, OutputSheet!A:A, 0))`.  In general, it helps keep straight the input/output and prevents any issues with the reference to X column within the total look-up range, which supports longevity.  Note that I used the whole column reference in my example here, though it will always be faster to have a fixed range, e.g., B1:B100.